# How does the definition of scanr in terms of foldr work?

Tags: haskell, fold

Exercise 1 at page 102 of the Haskell Wikibook asks "Write your own definition of scanr, first using recursion, and then using foldr." I wrote a recursive one:

```
myscan f acc []     = [acc]
myscan f acc (x:xs) = val : rest where
    val  = f x (head rest)
    rest = myscan f acc xs
```

...but couldn't figure out a foldr version. I eventually Googled and found this answer:

```
myscan2 f acc xs = foldr f' [acc] xs where
    f' x xs = (f x (head xs)) : xs
```

Obviously it works but it doesn't make sense to me. Using parameters

```
(+) 0 [1,2,3]
```

...it becomes something like this:

```
myscan2 (+) 0 [1,2,3] = foldr f' [0] [1,2,3] where
    f' [0] [1,2,3] = ((+) [0] (head [1,2,3])) : [1,2,3]
```

...but ((+) [0] (head [1,2,3])) part is not type compatible for (+). Yet, the function works, so what am I reading or converting incorrectly?

Comment: It's a simple conversion error, probably due to their dumb argument names. It should be `((+) 3 (head [0])) : [0]`. The accumulator is the second input to `foldr`'s function but they call the accumulator argument `xs` for some crazy reason.

Answer (score 3):

The matter on the function you found is:

1. The `xs` on `myscan2 f acc xs = foldr f' [acc] xs` is not the same on
   `f' x xs = (f x (head xs)) : xs`.

They are completly diferent. Maybe you could understand better if it looks like:

```
myscanr f acc xs = foldr f' [acc] xs
     where f' b a = (f b (head a)) : a
```

What it does, change the accumulator to a list, because scanl accumlate but it keep all the path going through the original list. So, `f'` `cons (:)` a new head applying the function `f` to the actual element of the list and the `head` of accumulator.

Comment: Obviously you must apply `reverse` because the returned list is backwards

Comment: I don't think it is backwards. This is a *right* scan, after all. Also, you renamed `x` to `b`, and I think leaving it as `x` would have made more sense.

Comment: You're right. I mistook :/ its `scanr` but i renamed both to show that, `f'` is not directly related to the variable on `myscanl f acc xs = foldr f' [acc] xs` (they could be name as you wish) Of course, its good name `b` as `x` and create more semantic.

Comment: I wouldn't call it `myscanl` when it's `scanr`!

Comment: Thank you for this. I can trace the working on paper even though I cannot grok it mentally just yet. Looking forward to when it's no longer inscrutable alien symbolism of enigmatic meaning. :)

Comment: The beginning is difficult, to switch context (imperative -> functional). I guess thats your case, like others and me included. But later, the functional paradigm is more natural. And Haskell's type system is beautiful. If it compiles, runs